# How can I Hide or Show Payment Methods depending upon Shipping Methods?

Tags: onepage-checkout, shipping-methods, payment-methods

Please note that I am using IWD Onepage checkout extension it gives all available **Shipping Methods** and **Payment Methods** on one page so I cant use $_POST to fetch shipping methods in this case.

What else can I do to show selective Payment Method based upon a certain Shipping Method?

Comment: Extension must be using some ajax calls to get payment methods after selection of shipping method, you should try there to intercept that call.

Answer (score 0):

This free [extension](https://github.com/ho-nl/Quanbit_QBShippingAndPaymentFilters) should works good with IWD Checkout